# Laravel Excel not chunking and timing out

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

Here is my controller action:

```
public function export() {

    (new ItemsExport)->queue('items.xlsx')->chain([
        new ExportItemsEmail(auth()->user()),
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'File will be emailed to you once done.');
}
```

Super simple, we queue up the export (there are over 5k records, can be more)

```
class ItemsExport implements FromQuery, ShouldQueue {

    use Exportable;

    public function query() {
        return Item::query();
    }
}
```

Again nothing fancy.

Issue: **Horizon fails**

I get this error in horizon:

> Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\AppendQueryToSheet has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. in /home/adam/Documents/flare/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:736

From [the docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html) this is suppose to chunk it and spin up many jobs. How ever in Horizon I see 2-3 jobs go through pending like no tomorrow, then one that stays before dying because of the above error.

**Am I doing this wrong?**

Comment: I know it has been a while, but did you get anywhere with this issue at all?
I am experiencing the exact same thing

Comment: anyone figure this out? I'm running into a similar problem - job just goes onto the queue and sits until timeout, and never processes.

Comment: Hey did u find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue on Laravel 8.6 with Excel 3.1.48, could not export large file due to timeout. In my case i also have Supervisor with many queue workers. It seems related to the issue [over here](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/3348) (when using simultaneous queue workers). The solution that worked for me is to:

1. Remove the ShouldQueue from the Export Class

   ```
   class ItemsExport implements FromQuery{

   use Exportable;

       public function query() {
           return Item::query();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create another Job Class and call the Export from there

   ```
     class ItemsExportJob implements ShouldQueue {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
        public function handle(){
           (new ItemsExport)->store('items.xlsx');
        }

     }
   ```
3. Call the Job Class from the Controller Class

   ```
    ItemsExportJob::dispatch();
   ```